# Access Automation with C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, automation

We have two programs for one customer.

1. One is an **Access Frontend** for customer and order management.
2. The other is **a .NET application**, in which all orders are displayed in a calendar.

In this calendar view, it is possible to select a job, which will then be displayed in `Access`. Currently, the selected job is written to the database and in `Access`, a timer runs in the main form, which periodically queries the database and displays the changed job.

This procedure should be changed, because an upgrade from `Access 2003` to `2010` will flicker the whole access program. There is the possibility to remotely control `Access` from `.NET`. This works fine on a single place. However, the two programs are used on a terminal server where about 20 people work with it at the same time.

Here is the code with which I use `Access`:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application objAccess = null;
        try
        {
            objAccess = GetAccessObject();
            object[] objArgs = new object[2];
            objArgs[0] = "SetAuftrAusOverview";
            objArgs[1] = m_int_CurrentOrderNo;
            RunAccessMacro(objAccess, objArgs);
            //RunAccessMacro(objAccess, new object[] 
              { "SetAuftrAusOverview", (object)m_int_CurrentOrderNo });
            //RunAccessMacro(objAccess, new object[] { "Csharp" });
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objAccess);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objAccess);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Fehler beim Macroaufruf");
        }

private Access.Application GetAccessObject()
    { 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application objAccess = null;

        Int32 intTries = 0;

        tryGetActiveObject:
        try
        {
            objAccess = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Access.Application");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            intTries++;
            if (intTries < 20)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                this.Activate();
                goto tryGetActiveObject;
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Access nicht erreichbar!");
            }      
        }

        return objAccess;
    }

private void RunAccessMacro(object oApp, object[] oRunArgs)
    {
        oApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oApp, oRunArgs);
    }
```

As I said, the code works great on a single-user system. It only works on the terminal server.

How do I get the access instance of the specific user? Or as an alternative: How can I get the selected order from the `.NET` program into the Access program without having to use a timer in `Access`?

Comment: What do you mean flicker access? IIRC soon as you query it will lock that table while it retrieves values, is that was you mean?

Comment: It looks like all the controls are hidden for a moment and then reappear. Under Access 2003, this phenomenon did not exist. It has only been created since the transition to Access 2010. Luckily, I'm still in the conversion phase, so that the customer does not notice

Comment: Sounds like the table locking, you can implement some sort of replication to prevent this, but with access AFAIK it can be quite difficult